# Enable-CsUser in lync server with c# remotly

Tags: c#, lync-2013

i want  Enable-CsUser trought c# from my server that in joined to my domain in my test lab

FQDN of lync server is lync.mohsen.com and I want enable "asadi" into my lync server("asadi" is exist in ldap and exchange")

this is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Remoting;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Security;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static SecureString GetSecurePassword(string password)
        {
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in password)
            {
                 securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            return securePassword;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string lyncUser = "administrator";
            string _pass = "abc@123";
            var lyncPW = GetSecurePassword(_pass);
            var fqdnlync = "lync.mohsen.com";
            var user = "asadi";
            var sipadd = "asadi@mohsen.com";
            // lync server 2013
            //this code is same as EXchange code in schima
            PSCredential creds = new PSCredential(lyncUser, lyncPW);

            WSManConnectionInfo conn = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://lync.mohsen.com/ocspowershell"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", creds);

            conn.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Default;

            Runspace runspace_2 = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(conn);
            PowerShell powershell_2 = PowerShell.Create();

            PSCommand command_2 = new PSCommand();
            command_2.AddCommand("Enable-CsUser");
            command_2.AddParameter("Identity", user);
            command_2.AddParameter("RegistrarPool", fqdnlync);
            command_2.AddParameter("SipAddressType", sipadd);
            powershell_2.Commands = command_2;

            try
            {
                runspace_2.Open();
                powershell_2.Runspace = runspace_2;
                powershell_2.Invoke();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //string er = ex.InnerException.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                runspace_2.Dispose();
                runspace_2 = null;

                powershell_2.Dispose();
                powershell_2 = null;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this code dont work!

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It would be nice if you give error message because of which your code is not working as expected. It is easy for other people to get you a solution or suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem myself

1. Be sure in lync server in IIS / internal(in my case)/ocspowershell/ authentication /windows authentication set to be enabled
2. Change  `var sipadd = "asadi@mohsen.com" ------->  var sipadd = "sip:asadi@mohsen.com"`

   3.Change

   `command_2.AddParameter("SipAddressType", sipadd); ----------> command_2.AddParameter("SipAddress", sipadd);`

ok thanx